# C# Expression change body (Property to SubProperty)

Tags: c#, expression

I create custom helper and need change expression body.

*Models*

```cs
public class Customer
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Report
{
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

*Using helper*

```cs
@Html.TextBoxForAdv(report => report.Customer)
```

```cs
public static MvcHtmlString TextBoxForAdv<TModel, TProperty>(
    this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper,
    Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> value)
{
   //value = { report.Customer };
   //At this place i want change Customer to Customer.Name
   string property = SomeFunction(typeof(Report)) return "Name";
   //value = { report.Customer.Name (from property) };

   return helper.TextBoxFor(helper, value);
}
```

I get property

```cs
Expression expr = Expression.Property(expression, "Name");
```

But new expression not valid to call helper.TextBoxFor(...)

How do it?

Comment: SubProperty is *Customer.Name*. Call is TextBoxForAdv(*report => report.Customer*). In TextBoxForAdv *report => report.Customer* must be replaced with *report => report.Customer.Name*. *.Name* is runtime value and can be another property of *Customer*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you are looking for:

```
public static MvcHtmlString TextBoxForAdv<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> value)
        {
            var body = Expression.Property(value.Body, "Name");
            var expression = Expression.Lambda<Func<TModel, string>>(body, value.Parameters[0]);
            return helper.TextBoxFor(expression);
        }
```